# Extend IsAjaxRequest() to include fetch api requests

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fetch-api, request-headers

I am currently building a site using MVC5 and I need to serve different content when an ajax request is made.

Usually we use jQuery and make an ajax request using `$.ajax`, but recently we have moved towards using the fetch api.  However, requests using the fetch api aren't registering with MVC as ajax requests so the wrong template is being used.

I have thought about making my own is ajax request extension but not sure what header to check for:

```
    public static bool IsAjaxOrFetchRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        if (request != null && request.Headers != null)
        {
            if (request.Headers["Custom-Fetch-Header"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
```

Is there a header that fetch sends with all requests like `Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"` ajax sends?

Stepping through the code, I couldn't see anything that stood out

Comment: Browsers always add the `Origin` request header to fetch requests and XHR requests that are sent cross-origin.

Comment: @sideshowbarker unfortunately they originate on the same site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok looking into this further, I cannot seem to find any standard header being sent with the  request so I have created my own header:

```
const request = new Request(url, {
  headers: new Headers({
    'X-Is-Ajax-Request': 'True'
  })
});

return fetch(request)
  .then(html => {
    const $result = $(html);
    const $content = $result.filter('.js-sidebar-panel-content');
    return $content.length ? $content : $result;
  });
```

Then I was able to update my extension with:

```
public static bool IsAjaxOrFetchRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    if (request != null && request.Headers != null)
    {
        if (request.Headers["X-Is-Ajax-Request"] != null)
        {
            return bool.Parse(request.Headers["X-Is-Ajax-Request"]);
        }
    }

    return request.IsAjaxRequest();
}
```

Comment: This works fantastically! But I am confused, why did you bother updating the extension, rather than using the default IsAjaxRequest() extension and send the {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"} like the other frameworks send?

Comment: So I could tell the difference between an ajax request and a fetch request if I needed to

Comment: @Pete has that come up in practice yet?

Comment: `{"X-Requested-With": "Fetch"}` would have been better.

Comment: Kenneth's solution is best as it requires no C# code changes to make the fetch look like a ajax request. Mat J's is good as it better complies with what is actually happens and provides consistency with telling the c# what method you are accessing it with, but then would require the additional coding to add an IsFetchRequest support method and then update your coding to be IsAjaxRequest || IsFetchRequest...

Passing in the X-Request-With as XMLHttpRequest was by far simpler and easier and only required adding the fetch option to make it work as desired.